# TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'now' of object '#<Performance>'

Tags: node.js, npm

I just upgraded node to the latest version v16.13.1
I attempted  to run an existing project but it crashed with this error:

```
performance.now = present;
                ^
TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'now' of object '#<Performance>'
    at Function.present.conflict (/Project_Path/node_modules/mstime/dist/cjs/present.js:39:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Project_Path/node_modules/mstime/dist/cjs/present.js:41:9)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (/Project_Path/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:485:14)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Project_Path/node_modules/mstime/dist/cjs/index.js:5:16)
```

Can someone explain to me this error and how to resolve it?

Comment: If we do not know what performance is it is hard to tell. Search for it in the project and give us some idea, preferably more code

Comment: Could you send us the project code.

Answer (score 6):

I just had this issue in some of my Jest unit tests after upgrading from node v14 to v16.

In my tests, I was spying on the `now()` method of `performance` to mock its implementation, but I was getting the same error message:

```js
jest.spyOn(performance, "now")
  .mockImplementationOnce(() => 1000)
  .mockImplementationOnce(() => 2000);

// TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'now' of object '#<Performance>'
```

As it suggests, the `now` property is readonly and cannot be reassigned. As a workaround, I used `Object.defineProperty` to make it writable. The mock implementations worked fine afterwards.

```js
// redefining readonly property of the performance object
Object.defineProperty(performance, "now", {
  value: jest.fn(),
  configurable: true,
  writable: true
});

// mocking an execution delta of 1000ms
jest.spyOn(performance, "now")
  .mockImplementationOnce(() => 1000)
  .mockImplementationOnce(() => 2000);

// ok now
```